# Swift youtube ios helper podfile 'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension)

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

After adding **OneSignal** to the project I get the following errors. I have tried **Require Only AppExtension-Safe API to No** in this pod file's settings and build successed but youtube pod file's functionality has broken, it does not open youtube videos after setting to no.

Could anyone give advice on how to solve this error? Thanks.

[image]

OneSignal target build phases.

[image]

Comment: If this is from Xcode 13 beta 3, see https://forums.swift.org/t/set-application-extension-api-only-on-a-spm-package/39333/18

Comment: It is 12.5.1...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are building both an app and an app extension. An app extension is standalone, it doesn’t have access for example to the app delegate. Solution: Don’t try to use the app delegate. It won’t compile. Check what files you include in your app extension target. Don’t include files that use the app delegate.

Comment: 1) "It looks like you are building both an app and an app extension?" Don't we need to build both of them? 2) I don't understand "Don’t try to use the app delegate" , there are no dependencies on OneSignal target's build phases, so can't figure out which files need to be removed. - I removed OneSignal extension from my main target and checked but it still shows me the same error. *Edited the question